# ng-bind on <title> doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

Using 1.3.0-rc1 (latest now).

I tried:

```
<title ng-bind="title"></title>

<title>{{title}}</title>
```

But nothing.

If I do `{{title}}` anywhere in `<body>` it works.

I'm doing:

```
app.main.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        if (current.hasOwnProperty('$$route')) {
            $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        }
    });
});
```

I can see my `title` in the model. What's going on with the `<title>` tag?

Comment: where did you define your app & controller? Make sure it's on the `<html>` tag

Comment: @DieterGoetelen yeah you are right, I forgot that, my `ng-app` was on `<body>` instead of `<html>`! Thank's

Comment: since this is answered you should answer the question or close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed by adding `ng-app` on `<html>` tag.